# what is the fast way to match words in text?

Tags: python, regex, string, list

i have a list of regex like :

```
regex_list = [".+rive.+",".+ll","[0-9]+ blue car.+"......] ## list of length 3000
```

what is the best method to match all this regex to my text

for example :

```
text : Hello, Owning 2 blue cars for a single driver
```

so in the output , i want to have  a list of matched words :

```
matched_words = ["Hello","4 blue cars","driver"]  ##Hello <==>.+llo
```

Comment: Match words more succinctly. Let's say this is a word: `\b\w+\b` - now get all your expressions in this form, e.g. `.+rive.+` becomes `\b\w+rive\w+\b`, `.+ll` becomes `\b\w+ll\b` so you don't match the whole text with one expression any more OR split your text by spaces and match your expressions against the single words. In that case, also iterate over your expressions and stop as soon as you get a match, moving on to the next word. Sorting your expressions by length beforehand, removing duplicates, merging expressions that do the same etc. may all be necessary, too. No way to tell as is.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, first of all, you will probably want to adjust your `regex_list`, because of now, matching those strings will give you the entire text back as match. This is because of `.+`, which states that there may follow any character any amount of time. What I have done here is the following:

```py
import re

regex_list = [".rive.",".+ll.","[0-9]+ blue car."]
text = "Hello, Owning 2 blue cars for a single driver"

# Returns all the spans of matched regex items in text
spans = [re.search(regex_item,text).span() for regex_item in regex_list]

# Sorts the spans on first occurence (so, first element in item for every item in span).
spans.sort()

# Retrieves the text via index of spans in text.
matching_texts = [text[x[0]:x[1]] for x in spans]

print(matching_texts)
```

I adjusted your `regex_list` slightly, so it does not match the entire text. Then, I retrieve all spans from the matches with the text. Additionally, I sort the spans on first occurence. Lastly, I retrieve the texts via the indexes of the spans and print those out. What you will get is the following

```
['Hello', '2 blue cars', 'driver']
```

NOTE: I am unsure why you would like to match '4 blue cars', because that is not in your text.

Comment: hello , thank you very your help but with search , it takes a lot of time with 3000 regex in the list

Answer (score 1):

You could also try this which is multi threaded version of [@Lexpj answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74768999/1668003)

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, as_completed
import re


# list of length 3000
regex_list = [".rive.", ".+ll.", "[0-9]+ blue car."]
my_string = "Hello, Owning 2 blue cars for a single driver "


def test(text, regex):
    # Returns all the spans of matched regex items in text
    spans = [re.search(regex, text).span()]

    # Sorts the spans on first occurence (so, first element in item for every item in span).
    spans.sort()

    # Retrieves the text via index of spans in text.
    matching_texts = [text[x[0]:x[1]] for x in spans]
    return matching_texts


with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as executor:
    futures = {executor.submit(test, my_string, regex)
               for regex in regex_list}

    # as_completed() gives you the threads once finished
    matched = set()
    for f in as_completed(futures):
        # Get the results
        rs = f.result()
        matched = matched.union(set(rs))
    print(matched)
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the desired result, your regexes are not correct. You don't want to match `.+`, but `\w+`, and also with the second regex, you'll want to match some letters *after* `ll` too.

The main idea is then to make one regex for all, by concatenating them with the `|` symbol:

```
import re

regex_list = [r"\w+rive\w+", r"\w+ll\w+", r"\d+ blue car\w+"]
regex = re.compile('|'.join(regex_list))
text = "Hello, Owning 2 blue cars for a single driver "
print(regex.findall(text))  # ["Hello","2 blue cars","driver"]
```

This still could give undesired effects when there is a part of your string that would match with *more than one* regex in the list. In that case the *first* will "win". So make sure that when multiple regexes could match the same text, they are ordered along their desired priority.